# How to get the shared person/account on one drive REST API?

Tags: rest, onedrive

One drive REST API could get the file metadata with property "shared",
but only could get the shared owner , doesn't get the shared person/account, how could I get the account that the file shared to somebody?

```
"shared": {
        "owner": {
            "user": {
                "displayName": "XXX xxx",
                "id": "xxx"
            }
        },
        "scope": "users"
    }
```

The property only get the owner, doesn't get the shared link/account to somebody? Can't find any resource on the document,anyone could help this

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to query the `permissions` facet on the item to get details on how the item is shared. The `shared` facet only provides some high level knowledge about the shared state of the item.

Have a read of [this documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/permissions.htm) and let us know if you have any questions.